# How to set an entire folder of files to copy always (or how to make files come in copy always as default) in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file

I would like an easier way to set the files in my solution to copy always without having to manually set each one (I have a lot of test files in a folder in one of my test projects and it's tedious to go through and set each one individually).

The only thing that works for me now is selecting each file and then changing the properties at once, but is there a way to have them come in as copy always so I don't have to worry about forgetting to set them and then run into problems when I'm testing because the files weren't copied to the output directory?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in .csproj file like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
<None Include="$(SolutionDir)FolderToCopy\**" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. I changed some files in that directory to "Do not copy" after adding what you showed to the .csproj file and they didn't copy. Not sure if that's the best way to test it though.

Comment: Based on the answer and using a slight modification, what worked for me on VS 2022 v17 was adding ```<ItemGroup><None Update="FolderToCopy\**"><CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory></None></ItemGroup>```.